# can we use one argument for two contextual filters

Tags: views

can we use one argument for two contextual filters **OR**
can we create and pass dynamic argument from one filter to another by using validation php code in first one?

drupal7.com/location-map/region-or-type-field-here

i want to use contextual filter for region and type fields for same argument.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE" on the contextual filter to "Provide Default Value" and set "Type" to "Raw value from URL" and set the Path component, in case of example provided in your question, Path component 0 is `location-map` and Path component 1 is `region-or-type-field-here`

Comment: after setting above settings in validation code for that field how can i retrieve that argument? by $argument or $view->args(number). i tried both ones but didn't get result. can we able to trace in validation code what value argument is getting.

Comment: But this way, the preview function of the view doesn't work

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. it should work if you provide it correct parameters via the given textfield.